# How do I add a row of zeros to a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

In matrix, we should put row of zeros before row with index K (not replacing row[k-1], but like putting row of zeros beetween row[k] and row[k-1]).

Function named 'change' works not in a way it's supposed to. This function replaces row[k] and adds extra row of zeros.

For example, I have [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] and I wanna get [[1,2,3], [0,0,0], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]], so I enter K = 1. But instead of what I want to get, I get  [[1,2,3], [0,0,0], [0,0,0],[7,8,9]].
bb is for matrix, kk is for row index.

```
def change(bb, kk):
    n = len(bb)
    bb.append([0]*2*n)
    n = len(bb)

    for i in range(n-1, kk-1, -1):
        bb[i] = bb[i-1]

    for j in range(0, 2*n-2):
        bb[kk][j] = 0

    return bb
```

Comment: "I have mistake" is not a sufficient description of the error.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code and narrow down the problem into a [mre]. 
Then ask a specific question. _"Why is my code doing this"_ is [too broad for Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/843953)
Please also take the [tour], read [ask] and [what's on-topic](/help/on-topic). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Also, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include your code as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to try this sample:

```
import copy              # if need to make a extra new copy - deepcopy

matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
         [4, 5, 6],
         [7, 8, 9]]
         
kk = 1  # k must be less than the len(matrix)

def change(kk, matrix):
    new_matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)         # only need this, if to make a new Matrix
    
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        if i == kk:
            new_matrix.insert(i, [0]*len(row))  # if need to return a new copy
            # matrix.insert(i, [0]* len(row))   # OR in-place modify & comment above line;  next line: return new_matrix
        
            
    return new_matrix                           # comment out, if in-place change
        
    
print(change(kk, matrix))
```